# What happen. blender 2.80 is not working on my pc { window 7 32bit }

Tags: error

Previous blender version was download and open successfully. But the upgrade version of blender 2.80 did'nt open on my pc {window 7 32bit}. Telling me that I need to get latest driver graphics cards.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade the drivers for the graphic card? Have you checked that your system meets the minimum requirements for 2.8 (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will Download it and give you feedback. Thanks Once again.